# Value from one Control in a View to one in another View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

In one of my views is a `Slider` element. The value from this one should change the value of a `control` in another `view`. I call the same `DataContext` which contains the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface but without success.
Do I missunderstood something important?

Comment: Generally speaking you should just be able to bind directly to another element's DP, but unless you post some code it's impossible for anyone to tell you for sure what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Are you saying that two views are sharing the same view model? If that's the case any change to a property used by both views for the slider should affect both views immediately if change notification was properly implemented.

Comment: Double check that `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `Mode` is properly set, and that the UIs share the identical data context. Break at `get` just after the value is changed. Anyway a snippet of your code will help.